# ImageView without xml definition

Tags: android, imageview

I want to create a dynamic number of ImageViews in Android.
But to display these ImageViews I have to create them in the main.xml (Am I right?)
Is there a way to display the ImageViews without creating them in the main.xml?

Comment: no you can create them dynamically
like
ImageView image=new ImageView(this);

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create them dynamically like this:

```
ImageView image=new ImageView(this);
```

and to set image in this dynamically created view use:

```
image.setImageResource(R.drawable.yourimage);
```

Comment: Yes, but i'm only able to show this ImageView if i write something like this

ImageView iv = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageview1);

Comment: you dont have to write any code like that . Create alinear layout dynamically and add as many imageview in that perticular linearlayout you want

Answer (score 0):

Put your image `my_image.jpg` into `res/drawable/my_image.jpg` and use:

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.ImageView;

public class Main extends Activity {
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        final ImageView imageView = new ImageView(this);
        imageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.my_image);
        setContentView(imageView);
    }
}
```

Tested on Android 22 with the default template generated by `android create project [...]`.